# Jet Airways Cancellation on connecting ticket

Tags: cancellations, klm, code-share, jet-airways

I have a flight soon from VIE-AMS-BLR. The VIE-AMS part is operated by KLM, but the second leg is operated by Jet, who recently suspended all international flights. My  ticket is from KLM, so who should I contact for this? And since flight tickets are going to be very expensive, is it likely that I will get any form of rerouting?

Comment: Have you tried contacting KLM? Do you have travel insurance?

Answer (score 1):

It do not matter who operate the flight. If your ticket is bought from KLM, they should reroute you, and eventually compensate you (but if the flight were scheduled after 7 or 14 days the cancellation, the compensation rules changes a bit).

I suggest you to go to KLM site and register yourself and your flight, so that KLM could contact you in case of changes, and possibly you will see the option you can have. [Good to have some ideas of alternatives before contacting an airline].

In any case you should also contact KLM (or the company which issued you the ticket).

Comment: Well, my flight is on the 11th of May. So I don't think there will be any compensation then?

Comment: It depends on the delay. You will have not refreshment or hotel, and the delay should be longer than usual rules (for compensation). [And compensations are always very difficult to get: airlines uses a lot of delays and excuses]. But you will get help and rerouting.